# Creating dynamic form in Formtastic based on key/value store

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, formtastic

I'm creating an app in rails that stores form definitions as key/value pairs in the database. It's basically an online form builder.

Storing the data is the easy part, but I'm trying to use formtastic to render the dynamically created forms. Been searching everywhere and couldn't find a solution.

Is there a way to dynamically generate the form based on a collection of key/value pairs?

Something like:

```
<% @form.fields.each do |f| %>
     <!-- RENDER FIELDS HERE -->
<% end %>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: make any progress on this?

Comment: Not with formtastic. A colleague of mine did it with standard html, but I'd still love to know how to do it with formtastic.

Comment: Can you give more detail on what you mean by key value? List out how you are storing the data.

Answer (score 0):

```
<% @form.fields.each do |f| %>
  <!-- RENDER FIELDS HERE -->
<% end %>
```

This could work except you are overwriting your formtastic object with the new local variable f that is now the field object.